# Facebook application share to wall with JS variable

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have:

```
$.post( "https://host.com/save.php", {
    'fb_id': userID,
    'meth': 'get_db_ID'
}, function(data) {

    link_id = data;
    console.log('from method' + link_id);
});

FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'My title for a link.',
    caption: ' ',
    description: 'My description',
    link: 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/Page-Test/1417010325197563?id=1417010325197563&sk=app_1413297985570561&app_data=u_id|'+link_id,
    picture: 'http://host.com/myimage.png'
}, 
function(response) {
    console.log('publishStory response: ', response);
});
```

But the var `link_id` I have defined previously and have assigned a user's id, doesn't display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem caused by asynchronous events. The link_id is set in the callback function for the $.post. This callback function only runs once the POST request is complete - this could be a few seconds depending on the connection. But, the code after the $.post runs straight away - meaning the link_id is not set when you make the FB.ui call. Try this instead:

```
$.post( "https://host.com/save.php", {
    'fb_id': userID,
    'meth': 'get_db_ID'
}, function(data) {

    link_id = data;
    console.log('from method' + link_id);

    FB.ui({
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'My title for a link.',
        caption: ' ',
        description: 'My description',
        link: 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/Page-Test/1417010325197563?id=1417010325197563&sk=app_1413297985570561&app_data=u_id|'+link_id,
        picture: 'http://host.com/myimage.png'
    }, 
    function(response) {
        console.log('publishStory response: ', response);
    });
});
```